# How to make method return class wrapping generic

Tags: java, spring-boot

A class has a similar type of method (let's call it a collector). I think these methods can be a method by making it return a class wrapping generic values.

This is example code

```java
public class Collector {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    /*I want to make method like this without making the Collector Class with generic value */
    public APICallResultDto<T, V> collectData() {
        APICallResultDto<T, V> result = new APICallResultDto<>();

        /* boiler plate
        * (1) complete request url
        * (2) call api
        * (3) validate response
        * (4) transform data
        * */

        return result;
    }
```

This code produce errors `Cannot resolve symbol 'T'` & `Cannot resolve symbol 'V'`

I know I can solve this problem by making Collector class with generic values. I want to Collector class to be singleton, I mean the bean. So I can't do that.

Is there any way?

Comment: Define T and V in the **method**.

Comment: Note that you won't be able to "pick" a URL or the like based on what T and V are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will compile if you add `<T, V>` in front of return type, as shown below:

```
public <T, V> APICallResultDto<T, V> collectData() {
    //...
}
```

For reference: [Generic Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html)